# Tags on badge question list

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, tumbleweed-badge

I'm trying to get the Weed-Eater hat on Stack Overflow. To do so, I'm looking at the list of questions [recently awarded the Tumbleweed badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed). The problem is, no tags show up there, and so it's rather difficult to see which ones I have a shot at. Any chance of showing the tags on this page?

I realize that getting this before Winter Bash is over would be difficult, but it would be good to keep such things in mind for the future.

Comment: Probably not before the end of winterbash.

Comment: Sadly I realize that, but I still feel obligated to ask...

Comment: Well, this is not directly related to winter bash, retagged.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411300/tumbleweed-posts-per-tag) to help you with this:

```sql
select top 100 p.Id as [Post Link]
,      p.tags
from   Posts p
join   PostTags pt
on     pt.PostId = p.Id
join   Tags t
on     t.Id = pt.TagId
where  p.Score <= 0
and    p.AnswerCount = 0
and    p.CommentCount = 0
and    p.ClosedDate is NULL
and    p.CreationDate < DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
and    t.TagName = ##tag:string##
order
by     p.CreationDate desc
```

It will show you the 100 most recent tumbleweed posts for the tag of your choice.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a search like [`created:..7d score:0 is:q answers:0 closed:no views:..15` and click "newest"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=created%3a..7d%20score%3a0%20is%3aq%20answers%3a0%20closed%3ano%20views%3a..15) (i.e. the open questions with the age of at least 7 days, zero score, and views limited to 15* just in case), though it doesn't take into account that there should be no comments.

Anyway, you can specify tags for this search, and most results would have no comments (you can also try decreasing views).

<sup>*there are still questions with slightly more than 15 views, blame caching</sup>